# As a voltage source voltage increases, how does the internal resistance increase?

Tags: voltage, resistance, impedance, voltage-source

As title says, supposes that maximum voltage of AC voltage source, or just voltage of DC voltage source, increases, because voltage source equipment is changed. What happens to internal resistance of the source? Is there any rule to how internal resistance changes? More maximum voltage, more internal resistance?

Comment: Depends on many, many factors.

Comment: There is no rule.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the power supply technology. Some kinds of voltage sources can supply large currents while (mostly) maintaining their voltage (lead-acid batteries, f/ex), while others' voltage sags when its load draws more than a few 10s of milliamps (such as a 9v "transistor" or smoke-detector battery). A bench power supply could be designed to supply a user-adjustable voltage with an essentially constant degree of sag per amount of current. There is no universal, physical rule; different kinds of voltage sources behave differently.